# Proof that $\langle[\hat{H},\hat{O}]\rangle=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

How can I show that for a particle in an infinite square well in a stationary state, that the expectation value $\langle[\hat{H},\hat{O}]\rangle=0$ where $\hat{H}$ is the Hamiltonian operator and $\hat{O}$ is an arbitrary operator?

Answer (score 0):

> The stationary states may have even or odd symmetry. If $\hat{O}$ is a unitary operator representing some symmetry, then it can be said that $\hat{H}$ is invariant under that symmetry provided that the Hamiltonian is invariant under conjugation by $\hat{O}$, i.e.
>   \begin{align}
>   \hat{O}^{-1} \hat{H} \hat{O} = \hat{H}.
> \end{align}
>   This condition can also be written as $[\hat{H},\hat{O}]=0$.

This question would be better answered on http://www.physics.stackexchange.com.

Here are the reference and one other link which pose a similar question:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79296/simple-quantum-mechanics-question-about-the-commutator-of-translation-operators
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/symmetric-potential-and-the-commutator-of-parity-and-hamiltonian